# pg_stat_all_indexes shows 0 idx_scan even index is used

Tags: postgresql

I can see that index is actually used in a query by using explain but pg_stat_all_indexes table shows 0 for that index. (all idx_scan, idx_tup_read and idx_tup_fetch are 0)

- When this statictics are updated?
- How can I see how many times my index is used?

Comment: EXPLAIN without ANALYZE does not actually run the query.  Are you sure your query is ever getting actually run?

Comment: Is track_counts turned on?  Do you get log messages about problems with the statistics collector?

Comment: @jjanes I run this  EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, COSTS, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, FORMAT JSON)

Comment: @jjanes i will check track_counts. Btw quite long time later idx_scan turned to 1. But I actually run this query at least 20 times and saw that index is used

Comment: Is the statistics collector process running? Anything weird about stale statistics or similar in the log file?

Comment: @jjanes track_counts is on (even it is commented out in postgresql.conf when I run following query it is shown as "on" query: SELECT *
FROM pg_settings 
WHERE name LIKE 'track_counts%')